# Cannot read property 'selectedIndex' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a big problem with my code. On fiddle he works  but on my page i get Cannot read property 'selectedIndex' of undefined and only work the first function with id #minbeds other make in the console error.
How can i repair it or change?

```
link
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5o5dtfwj/

Comment: You should post code here, not just a link to a fiddle. It will better your chances of getting help. You should review [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Where do you load your script? In the head? End of body? Do you use document ready?

Comment: As it works on fiddle, i doubt we will be able to reproduce your error ourselves. consider adding an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve